# Expandablelistview inside a customised scrollview class

Tags: android, expandablelistview, android-gridview, android-scrollview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I have customized-scrollview class that allows me to scroll up/down using a rotor (similar to the mouse click-wheel), it extends scrollview and inside it I have an `ExpandableListView`, I need to scroll the entire view.

I went through some of the solution provided, like disable the scrolling, used, tried fixing the height of the widget (ELV), but the scrolling with my rotor hardware doesn't happen

```
<com.my.android.widget.CustomScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/encoder_exp_scroll">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/list_of_controls"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:childDivider="#00000000"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:focusable="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</com.my.android.widget.CustomScrollView>
```

The entire view should scroll with touch and rotor events as well.